# How do I ask user to input a variable?

Tags: java, variables, input

How would I get the user to input H and for the code to assign another variable the value of H?

Like if the user inputs a letter that matches a previously defined variable(H for example) how would

I put that input next to an double variable to make it equal the previous variable

Its hard to explain but look for the error comment and you'll see what I mean

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        double H = 1.008;
        double Du = 5.303;
        double Bz = 8.148;
        double Ju = 10.026;
        double Nu = 14.289;
        double M = 14.759;
        double Af = 17.298;
        double Et = 18.77;
        double Z = 16.515;
        double Sl = 20.47;
        double Di = 21.435;
        double Bo = 23.953 ; 
        double Az = 28.302;
        double P = 32.248;
        double Hd = 32.636;
        double Tm = 35.085;
        double R = 36.501;  
        double V = 38.853;
        double Nv = 41.623;
        double A = 42.385;
        double T = 44.466;
        double Ha = 46.224;
        double Jo = 49.014;
        double Fg = 50.835;
        double K = 51.241;
        double Ea = 54.241;
        double B = 57.546;
        double Lu = 61.416;
        double Do = 66.244;
        double Qu = 68.081;
        double En = 70.787;
        double Ka = 72.317;
        double W = 75.462;
        double Of = 79.264;
        double Da = 81.047;
        double Re = 84.941;

        System.out.print("\n What elements");
        String elementletter1 = inp.nextLine();
        double element1 = elementletter1; // error
        System.out.print("\n How many");
        double element1num = inp.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("\n What elements");
        String elementletter2 = inp.nextLine();
        double element2 = elementletter2; // error
        System.out.print("\n How many");
        double element2num = inp.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("what");
        String what = inp.nextLine();

        if (what.equals("moles")) {
            System.out.println("How many grams");
            double grams = inp.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("moles=" + (grams / ((element1 * element1num) + (element2 * element2num))));
        }
        else if (what.equals("grams")) {
            System.out.println("How many moles");
            double moles = inp.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("grams=" + (moles * ((element1 * element1num)   + (element2 * element2num))));
        }
        else if (what.equals("per")) {
            System.out.println("grams per mole =" + (((element1 * element1num) + (element2 * element2num))));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope that you understand that the name of a variable, like Da and Re are merely for the use of the compiler and the programmer. The actual program doesn't know about the variable name, nor should it.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to store the element symbol and its mass into a [Map](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_map_interface.htm):

```java
final Map<String, Double> elementMass = new HashMap<>();
elementMass.put("H", 1.008);
```

Then you'll be able to easily translate an element symbol to its mass:

```java
Double element1 = null;
while (element1 == null) {
  System.out.print("\n Enter an element symbol: ");
  final String element1Line = inp.getLine().trim();
  element1 = elementMass.get(element1Line);
  if (element1 != null) break;
  System.out.print("Unrecognized symbol " + element1Line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double element1 =elementletter1; //error
```

In this line, you are assigning a `string` type value to `double` type variable. That's wrong. Next, according to your code, you do not even need to use `string` type variable for comparison. That's not the correct way of inputting some value and expecting to get totally different typed value. Just take the value in double, and then compare it or use it accordingly. Or in your case, you have to use data structure for this. I recommend you to use `Hash Map`. Like;
Import the HashMap class:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
```

Try this

```
HashMap<String, Double> elementMassesHash = new HashMap<>();
elementMassesHash.put("H", 1.008);
```

OR this

```
HashMap<String, Double> elementMassesHash = new HashMap<String, Double>();
elementMassesHash.put("H", 1.008);
```